# Linking CSS, HTML IN NODE.JS

Tags: html, css, node.js

I'm trying to add some styling to a very simple app I did with Node.js. 
I tried all the answers possible but the CSS file continue without showing up. 
I'd be glad if someone could help me to spot the error :) 
Thanks in advance.

I'm working in goormIDE.

**My folders:**

```
>app.js
>public
    >css
      >styles.css
>views
  >search.ejs
```

**My code in app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require("request");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("search");
  });

app.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var query = req.query.search;
    var url = "http://omdbapi.com/?s=" + query + "&apikey=thewdb";
    request(url, function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render("searchresults", {data: data});
        }
    });
});

app.listen(9000, function(){
    console.log("Movie App has started!!!");
});
```

**search.ejs:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Central Cinema</title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" 
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/css/styles.css"/>
    </head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="landing-header">
            <h1>Search For a Movie</h1>

            <form action="/results" method="GET">
                <input type="text" placeholder="search term" name="search">
                <input type="submit">
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

**styles.css**

```
body {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: I think just remove `/` before `css` in the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/css/styles.css"/>`

Comment: I tried that already :) and it didn’t solve the problem.

Comment: can you please show the output, Do try one thing, Being on web page Press `ctrl+u` then click on this line `/css/styles.css` you will know that whether css being liked or not and if yes then what's the URL for the css

Comment: Hi Pattnaik, 
This is what I get when I check the website source:
Am I missing something there??

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Central Cinema</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="css" href="/css/styles.css">
    </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="landing-header">
    <h1>Search For a Movie</h1>
    <form action="/results" method="GET">
         <input type="text" placeholder="search term" name="search">
         <input type="submit">
    </form> 
   </div>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css"/>
```

> Just remove the type="css" from link